# How can I search through grandparent record to find different child records?

Tags: soql

`Income__c` is a child of `Borrower__c` which is in turn a child of `Loan__c`. `Scenario__c` is also a child of `Loan__c`, all of these with Master/Detail relationships. I have a list of income records, and need a list of the grandparent loan's child scenarios. Basically something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Scenario__c
WHERE Loan__r.Borrowers__r.Income__r.Id IN :incomeIds
```

Is this possible with a single SOQL query?

Comment: Hi @Chuck, just to clarify have you tried the query you have in your question? If so, could you edit your question with any errors you are getting. As it is written, you should be able to execute that query. One thing I would recommend though is to use Loan__r.Borrowers__r.Income__c and the additional step to use the Id on that Income record is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, one would use the [semi-join feature of SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm?q=semi-join)

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Scenario__c 
      WHERE Loan__c IN
        (SELECT Borrower__r.Loan__c 
            FROM Income__c WHERE Id IN: incomeIds)
```

but this won't work because the subquery can't use relationship fields

> The selected column in a subquery must be a foreign key field, and can’t traverse relationships. This limit means that you can’t use dot notation in a selected field of a subquery.

So, you're going to need two queries

- One to get all the `Income__c` including the grandparent field `Borrower__r.Loan__c`
- One to get all the `Loan__c` with children `Scenario__c`

Use maps to correlate the two so you can see for a given `Income__c.Id` the `Scenario__c` for the common (grand)parent `Loan__c`